# How to decide earth trace width in protection circuit?

Tags: circuit-protection, trace, earth

I am using the earth trace for protection circuit in telecom system. The protection circuit includes MOV, sidactor & fuse.  So please suggest How to calculate the Earth trace width.

Answer (score 0):

The Track current capacity should be more than the MOV rating. So whenever the MOV acts, the fuse will open up safely without burning the tracks. You can use the resistance formula rL/A to calculate the current capability/dissipation of the copper track/conductor. You can improve the PCB track capacity by removing solder mask at that particular area.

Comment: Is it same in sisactor case also? what happen in sidactor case. or high voltage surge/spike case.

Comment: Yes. sidactor is also just like a back to back zener. The fuse should blown before the sidactor melts.